# getting a sprite to jump multiple times

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using a vector to store jump values and then use them to get the sprite to jump. so far I  have got the sprite to move horizontally but not to move vertically.

```
void vec_jump()
{
    vector<float> move_sprite;

    for (float x = -14.0f; x <= 14.0f; x += 2.0f)
    {
        y = (-0.1f*(x*x)) + 20.0f;
        move_sprite.push_back(y);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < move_sprite.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << move_sprite[i] << endl;
        y = move_sprite[i];
        x += 2.0f;
    }
}

void handleKeypress(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case 27:
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 32:
        vec_jump();
        break;
```

Comment: I have moved the jumpsprite function and it moves only when the space bar  is hit, I want it to move completely when the space bar is hit and to move completely again when the space bar is hit just like a platformer.

Answer (score 1):

This comes down to physics more than anything.  Jumping gives something an upward velocity; gravity is a force, which creates an acceleration, which is the rate of change of a velocity.  So it's not enough to store the position of the sprite; you need to store its velocity as well, and then on your periodic updates you need to:

- apply the velocity to the position, and
- apply the the acceleration due to gravity to the velocity.

Your code could look something like this:

```
void updateSprite()
{
  x += dx;
  y += dy;

  dy -= GRAVITY;

  if(y <= 0) { dy = 0; y = 0; }
}
```

and then in your keypress handler:

```
if(key == SPACE)
{
  dy += JUMP_SPEED;
}
```

Separately, you don't really want to have your update loop be initiated by pressing the jump key like you have it now; that should be separate.